# Does Observable have a do if operator?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

My situation is I'm opening a dialog, want to `switchMap` to another observable only if the dialog observable returns a `true` value, otherwise, display an error and stop the following actions.

Currently I have the following:

```
   this.dilog.open(DialogComponent)
    .afterClosed()
    .takeUntil(this.end$)
    .do(item => {
      if (!item) {
        this.error = 'Please accept the agreement to continue.'
        this.isSubmitting = false;
      }
    })
    .filter(item => !!item)
    .switchMap(item => anotherObservable)
```

I want to improve the readability of this code.

Comment: As far as i can see, the observable chain does what you want it to do. Am I missing something?

Comment: What I would like acheive is something like 

  `this.dialog.opne(DialogComponent).if(#onTrue () => setError , #onFalse() => switchMap )`

Comment: That kind of operator isn't available, but I'm not sure I see the problem with what you have already. Are you not happy with the readability?

Comment: yes the readability is not that good, any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're not on version 5.5 of RxJS, which let's you more easily [create your own operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md). Below is a function to hopefully improve readability when glancing at the code in a few months time:

```
// source: source observable
// onError: function to execute on error
// onSuccess: observable to switchMap to
function showErrorOrSwitchMap(source, onError, onSuccess) {
    return source
        .do(item => {
            if (!item) {
                onError();
            }
        })
        .filter(item => !!item)
        .switchMap(item => onSuccess)
}

// USAGE
showErrorOrSwitchMap(
    this.dilog.open(DialogComponent)
        .afterClosed()
        .takeUntil(this.end$),
    function() {
        this.error = 'Please accept the agreement to continue.'
        this.isSubmitting = false;
    },
    anotherObservable
); // You can continue the observable chain here if you want
```

This is just your code, moved inside a function. While it doesn't change your original code, it (hopefully) makes it more readable where the function is used.